# ¿Como puedo eliminar los datos multiplos de 3 de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode, programación-móvil, tuplas

```
# Escribir un programa que almacene el abecedario en una lista, elimine de la lista las 
# letras que ocupen 
# posiciones múltiplos de 3, y muestre por pantalla la lista resultante.
def funcion():
    #En este lugar contengo todo el abecedario
    abc= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    #Puede ser en el for siguiente en donde me sale un error, list index out of range
    for i in range(len(abc)):
        if i%3==0:
            #pongo el abc.remove para remover cada vez que el modulo de i%3 sea 0
            abc.remove(abc[i])
    #En este apartado imprimo
    print(abc)
#Y esto para activar la función
funcion()
```

Para ser mas especificos dudo de la siguiente parte del codigo, en el que segun tengo entendido cuando se eliminan el dato i cuando su modulo es 0 y se empieza a recorrer, en donde el rango cambia y por eso sucede el error

Comment: deberías trabajar recorriendo con una copia de la lista para modificar la original según su index

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi solución:

**Código**

```
def funcion():

    abc= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    #Necesitamos saber cuál es la cantidad total de abecedario que será al final. Para eso divido 27/3 = 9. En esos 9 contamos inclusive el 0
    abcd= len(abc) - int(len(abc)/3)
    #Coloco la función de abcd en el for loop para que ahora si el index este dentro de rango:
    for i in range(0,abcd):
        if i%3==0:

            abc.remove(abc[i])

    print(abc)

funcion()
```

**Produce:**

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'q', 'r', 's', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

El problema es que remueve los múltiplos de 3 a partir de la lista que se va actualizando. Por lo que considero que lo deseable es que remueva los múltiplos de 3 en base al abecedario total.

Por lo que cree este código:

**Código:**

```
def funcion():

    abc= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    abc_final = []
    for i in range(len(abc)):
        if i%3!=0:
            abc_final += abc[i]

    print(abc_final)

funcion()
```

**Produce:**

```
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'ñ', 'p', 'q', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'z']
```

Me avisas si te sirvió.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo esta removiendo elementos de la lista, por cada iteracion multiplo de tres, la lista se reduce en 1, por lo que en la iteracion 21 la lista que originalmente contenia 27 elementos ahora solo continen 20, por lo que `abc.remove(abc[i])` esta tratando de remover un elemento que esta por fuera de la lista.

Corre este codigo:

```
def funcion():
        abc= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
        for i in range(len(abc)):
            print(f'numero i: {i} tamano de la lista {len(abc)}')
            if i%3==0:
                print(i%3)
                abc.remove(abc[i])

funcion()
```

Antes de que el el interprete te de el error vas a ver que el contador esta en 21 (i=21) pero el tamano de la lista es 20. por eso el error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Pudes usar algo como esto:

```
def funcion():
        abc= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
        counter = [i for i in range(len(abc)) if i%3==0][1:]
        new_abc = []
        for i in range(1,len(abc)):
            if i not in counter:
                new_abc.append(abc[i-1])
        print(f'{new_abc}')
funcion()
```

en la linea `counter = [i for i in range(len(abc)) if i%3==0][1:]` simplemente estoy creado una lista de numeros multiplos de 3 y luego quitando el primer elemento `0`

Te da un resultado asi:

```
['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y']
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Concepto

Cuando tienes este tipo de escenarios, modificar la lista original trae algunas complicaciones como las que tienes ahora. Lo mejor es crear una nueva lista con los datos de la anterior que cumplen cierta condición.

```
[item for i, item in enumerate(abc, start=1) if(i % 3 != 0)]
```

###### Explicación

Esta extraña sintaxis se llama [comprensión de lista](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones) y es una forma corta, bonita y eficiente de crear una lista usando un bucle for.

La función enumerate nos devuelve un iterador, pero para simplificar esta respuesta imagina que devuelve una lista del estilo `[(start, item[0]), (start+1, item[1]), ... (start+n, item[n])]`. A cada tupla la [desempaquetamos](https://pharos.sh/unpacking-en-python-mas-alla-de-la-asignacion-paralela) en dos. Hacemos que start empiece en 1, ya que así podremos saltar los items cuya posición sea multiplo de 3.